# Setting Visibility of Floating Action Button in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm making `ViewPager` in Activity and Fragments in `ViewPager`. I have made a floating action button in activity. I want to make floating action button invisible when user moves to certain fragment. I have tried to do this by adding code `fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` into `onResume` of the certain fragment, but it doesn't work properly. How can i set visibility programmatically?

"CertainFragment.java"

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    FloatingActionButton fab =(FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_button_circle_board);
    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

"certain_activity's_layout.layout"

`

```
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/circle_board_viewpager">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fab_button_circle_board"
                app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu_circle_board"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
                app:miniFabBackgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:miniFabTitleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:miniFabDrawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
      </FrameLayout>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pagechangelistener to your viewpager(in Activity) and change the floating button's visibility in that.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

@Override public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
  changeFab(position); }

private void changeFab(final int currentTabPosition) {

    switch (currentTabPosition) {
        case 0:
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case 1:
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        case 2:
           fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;
        default:
           fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **CallBack**, when that user enter that Fragment,call the method of CallBack, and set the button invisible in the method in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the preload of ViewPager when use ViewPager+Fragments.

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        FloatingActionButton fab =(FloatingActionButton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab_button_circle_board);
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

SetUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) be called when the fragment is visible.You can do something in it when fragment visible or invisible.